# Oracle SQL OR AND Statement

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a requirement like below where text in "" are passed from user

If  users chose “Tutte le Attività” no filters on this.
If users  chose “Solo Attività senza Impatto EHS” then  JOBPLAN.PRIORITY = null or JOBPLAN.PRIORITY <> 9
If users chose “Solo Attività con Impatto EHS” then JOBPLAN.PRIORITY = 9

I have written below code :
where condition ...

```
AND (('Tutte le Attività' = (:IMP))
  OR ('Solo Attività senza Impatto EHS' = (:IMP) and TAB1.PRI IS NULL OR TAB1.PRI NOT IN ('9'))
  OR ('Solo Attività con Impatto EHS' = (:IMP) and TAB1.PRI IN ('9')))
```

Where IMP are bind variables.

For some reason second condition is getting failed.

is my code right?

Comment: _is my code right?_ No

Comment: Kindly share sample data and desired result.

Answer (score 0):

`AND` has precedence over `OR`. So you need more parentheses:

```
OR ('Solo Attività senza Impatto EHS' = :IMP
    and (TAB1.PRI IS NULL OR TAB1.PRI NOT IN ('9'))
   )
```

Comment: Tried this , still condition fails. Not getting exepected result set

Comment: @user1838000: I don't see any other flaw. So you say that in spite of :IMP = 'Solo Attività senza Impatto EHS' you are getting rows with TAB1.PRI null and TAB1.PRI null?